# Permissão negada acessando arquivo

Tags: c, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Tenho uma função em meu programa aonde ela mostra todos os alunos cadastrados em um arquivo binária, o usuário seleciona qual ele deseja deletar, aparece uma tela de confirmação com os dados do usuário aguardando o *input* para então ocorrer a confirmação de exclusão.

Quando cadastro um aluno e o excluo, o programa funciona corretamente, após outro cadastro, não consigo mais excluir alunos. Segue abaixo a função.
Um `perror();` no `remove(arqAlunos)` me retorna o seguinte *string* `Permission Denied.`

```
void excluirAluno () {
// Declarações locais
    struct Alunos aluno;
    FILE *arqAlunos = NULL, *arqTemp = NULL;
    int posicaoArquivo = 0, totalPosicoes = 0, flag1 = 0, flag2 = 0, contador = 0;
    char opcao;
// Instruções
    do {
        posicaoArquivo = apresentaAlunos(); // Apresenta todos os alunos cadastrados no sistema (caso exista algum).
        arqAlunos = fopen(ARQ_ALUNOS, "rb"); // Abre para leitura.
        if (arqAlunos != NULL) { // Considera a existência do arquivo...
            fseek(arqAlunos, 0, SEEK_END); // Posiciona-se no final do arquivo.
            totalPosicoes = (ftell(arqAlunos) / sizeof(aluno)); // Cálculo do total de bytes na primeira posição do arquivo.
            if (posicaoArquivo != 0) { // Considera que existe ao menos um aluno cadastrado no sistema.
                fseek(arqAlunos, ((posicaoArquivo - 1) * sizeof(aluno)), SEEK_SET); // Posiciona-se na posição referente ao cálculo do segundo parâmetro.
                if (fread(&aluno, sizeof(aluno), 1, arqAlunos) == 1) { // Lê os dados do arquivo um a um.
                    flag1 = verificaAlunoMatriculado(aluno.matricula); // Verifica se o aluno está matriculado em algum curso.
                    clrscr();
                    desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 18, 70, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                    gotoxy(11,11);
                    printf("%-19.19s%-14.14s%-13.13s%-13.13s", "NOME", "CPF", "SEXO", "MATRICULA");
                    gotoxy(11,12);
                    printf("%-16.16s%-9.11s %11.11s%13d", aluno.nome, aluno.CPF, aluno.sexo, aluno.matricula);
                    gotoxy(15,16);
                    printf("DESEJA EXCLUIR OS DADOS DESTE ALUNO? (S / N): ");
                    fflush(stdin);
                    scanf("%c", &opcao);
                    fflush(stdin);
                    opcao = toupper(opcao);
                    while ((opcao != 'S') && (opcao != 'N')) {
                        clrscr();
                        desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 14, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                        gotoxy(11,11);
                        printf("OPCAO INVALIDA");
                        gotoxy(11,12);
                        printf("UTILIZE [S] OU [N]");
                        gotoxy(11,13);
                        printf("SUA ESCOLHA: ");
                        fflush(stdin);
                        scanf("%c", &opcao);
                        fflush(stdin);
                        opcao = toupper(opcao);
                    }
                    if ((opcao == 'S') && (flag1 == 0)) { // Caso o usuário deseje remover um aluno e ele não esteja matriculado em algum curso.
                        clrscr();
                        arqTemp = fopen(ALUNOS_TEMP, "wb"); // Criação de um arquivo temporário para os alunos.
                        if (arqTemp != NULL) {
                            rewind(arqAlunos); // Vai para o início do arquivo.
                            while (!feof(arqAlunos)) { // Enquanto não atingir o final do arquivo.
                                if (fread(&aluno, sizeof(aluno), 1, arqAlunos) == 1) { // Lê dados um a um no arquivo.
                                    contador++; // Incremento do contador.
                                    if (contador != posicaoArquivo) { // Enquanto contador não atingir o total de registros gravados no arquivo...
                                        if (fwrite(&aluno, sizeof(aluno), 1, arqTemp) != 1) { // Gravará todos os dados originais no arquivo temporário.
                                            desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 12, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                                            gotoxy(11,11);
                                            printf("ERRO AO GRAVAR ARQUIVO TEMPORÁRIO.");
                                            getch();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (fclose(arqAlunos) != 0) { // Caso ocorra erro ao fechar o arquivo principal.
                                desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 13, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                                gotoxy(11,11);
                                printf("ERRO AO FECHAR O ARQUIVO PRINCIPAL.\n");
                                gotoxy(11,12);
                                perror("Erro");
                                getch();
                            }
                            else {
                                flag2 = 1;
                                if (fclose(arqTemp) != 0) { // Caso ocorra erro ao fechar o arquivo temporário.
                                    desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 13, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                                    gotoxy(11,11);
                                    printf("ERRO AO FECHAR O ARQUIVO TEMPORARIO.\n");
                                    gotoxy(11,12);
                                    perror("Erro");
                                    getch();
                                }
                                else {
                                    if (remove(ARQ_ALUNOS) != 0) { // Caso ocorra erro ao remover o arquivo principal.
                                        desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 13, 46, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                                        gotoxy(11,11);
                                        printf("ERRO AO REMOVER O ARQUIVO ALUNOS.\n");
                                        gotoxy(11,12);
                                        perror("Erro");
                                        getch();
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        if (rename(ALUNOS_TEMP, ARQ_ALUNOS) != 0) { // Caso ocorra erro ao renomear o arquivo temporário.
                                            desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 13, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                                            gotoxy(11,11);
                                            printf("ERRO AO RENOMEAR ARQUIVO.\n");
                                            gotoxy(11,12);
                                            perror("Erro");
                                            getch();
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            // Caso tudo ocorra corretamente, a mensagem abaixo será exibida.
                                            desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 12, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                                            gotoxy(11,11);
                                            printf("EXCLUSAO REALIZADA COM SUCESSO!");
                                            getch();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (flag1 == 1 && opcao == 'N') {
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (flag1 == 1) {
                            // 'flag1' indica que o aluno já está matriculado em algum curso, portanto não poderá ser excluido do sistema.
                            clrscr();
                            desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 13, 55, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                            gotoxy(11,11);
                            printf("ESTE ALUNO JA ESTA MATRICULADO EM UM CURSO.");
                            gotoxy(11,12);
                            printf("NAO PODERA SER REMOVIDO DO SISTEMA.");
                            getch();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag2 == 0) {
                if (fclose(arqAlunos) != 0) {
                    desenhaMoldura(10, 10, 13, 40, PRETO, BRANCO, 2, 1);
                    gotoxy(11,11);
                    printf("ERRO AO FECHAR O ARQUIVO ALUNOS.\n");
                    gotoxy(11,12);
                    perror("Erro");
                    getch();
                }
            }
        }
    clrscr();
    } while (posicaoArquivo != 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O arquivo está aberto. Você não pode remover arquivos abertos. Precisa fechá-lo antes. Este erro indica que você não tem permissão justamente por isto.

Seu código está bastante confuso, é muito fácil se perder em que estado está o arquivo.

Há uma chance de você estar tentando fazer `remove(arqAlunos)` mas sei lá é um chute, não dá para entender o código. Mesmo que isto pareça resolver o problema, o código certamente tem outros problemas não tão aparentes. Código funcionando em um teste não significa que eles está certo.

Comment: Mas o arquivo que eu quero remover já é o primeiro a ser fechado na seção de if-else.

Comment: Não fechou. E note o segundo parágrafo da resposta. Como seu código está bem confuso você não percebe que não fechou ele.

Comment: Vou refazer meu código de exclusão de dados de arquivo. O que você recomendaria para deixar o código menos confuso e não reencontrar o problema de não saber qual o estado do arquivo.

Comment: Comece definindo um padrão claro de nomenclatura para o nome das variáveis preferencialmente o que é costume usar em C. Isso vale para formatação do código também, você não segue um padrão e mesmo quando segue é bem difícil de entender. Cada variável você usa um padrão e isto atrapalha. Sua "função" tenta fazer tudo, tente separar as diversas tarefas em outras funções. Não deixe grandes blocos de código, fica difícil ver onde termina, especialmente quando acumula com o próximo problema. Evite uma complexidade ciclomática tão grande, em outras palavras não tenha tantos níveis de endentação.

Comment: Tente separar a lógico do código da lógica de tratamento de erro. Evite tanta *flag*, quando tem muito é porque o código está mal estruturado. Lei código de outras pessoas que programam bem. Você notará que em nada se parece com o seu código. Se você não ver diferença, você terá problemas para programar. Não adianta comentar código quando o código sequer faz o que o comentário diz. Por isto a maioria dos programadores experientes (de verdade) pouco comentam códigos. Eles comentam "porque faz" e não "o que faz". E raramente precisa dizer porque faz se o código está bem escrito.